# Condition on symplectic form: $(d\alpha)^n \neq 0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

I started to read about contact and symplectic forms and I came across [this answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/56157).

It seems to state that the definition of symplectic form is that $d\alpha$ is non-degenerate if and only if $(d\alpha )^n \neq 0$ (pointwise).

Everywhere else non-degeneracy of a $2$-form $\beta$ is given as $\beta$ is non-degenerate if and only if $\beta(v,w)=0$ for all $w \in V$ implies $v =0$. Here $V$ is the vector space on which $\beta$ acts.

But it's not clear to me why these two definitions of non-degeneracy are equivalent.

> Please could someone explain to me why  $(d\alpha )^n \neq 0$ if and only if $d\alpha(v,w)=0$ for all $w \in V$ implies $v =0$?

Comment: That is not what the answer says. It says that this condition describes an exact symplectic structure. Here $\alpha$ is a $1$-form and $\omega = d \alpha$ is the symplectic form.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right, thank you for pointing it out. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

they're not!

typically you have a two-form $\omega$ such that $\omega^n$ is non-zero everywhere. The two-form is closed i.e. $d\omega=0.$

The non-zero everywhere is the same as saying that the two-form is non-degenerate everywhere.

It is often the case that there is a one-form such that 
$$
\omega = d\alpha
$$
that is it is exact (which is not always the case) but this is not always the case.

For cotangent bundles, $\omega = d\alpha.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After spotting a mistake in my understanding thanks to Qiaochu Yuan's comment I have edited my question.